# Reading from public effective user settings Error

Tags: ios10

In iOS 10, when I tried to upload photos form local photo library from my app, it crashed and give me the following error

System group container for `systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles`
and the path is `/private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2017-08-09 15:13:10.332520-0500  [MC] Reading from public effective user settings.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I fixed this. I went to the Plist file and added Privacy setting[image]

For more details please see here [Change Privacy Setting]
https://useyourloaf.com/blog/privacy-settings-in-ios-10/